# JQuery Allow Multiple Field Check Function

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple option for users to check the "title" or "username" for availability. The function runs the ttck.php and displays the appropriate alert. Problem is the function() will not reset to allow multiple checks without reloading the entire page.

```
function checkTitle() { 
         $.post('ttck.php', $(".pubttl").serialize(), function(data) 
                { $('.tresult').html(data).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow'); });
                      }


<span class="udo" onclick="checkTitle()"> check title availability</span>
```

What am I not seeing here to reload/reset this event so users can check as many times as necessary?

EDIT: This is the PHP

```
if(empty($TITLE)) { echo 'Please enter a Title';} 
else { $que=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pubs` WHERE TITLE='$TITLE'"); 
$result=mysql_num_rows($que); 
if($result>0) { echo 'Sorry, Title is already published. Try an alternate'; } 
else { echo 'Huzzah, your Title is Available!'; }}
```

There are a few extended parameters in this statement, but none that would effect the function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
<span class="udo" onKeyUp="CheckTitle()"> check title availilibilty </span>
```

in your earlier script you were trying to run the function by using an Onclick function, whereas this one will run as the person is keying in the title. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Hi Mihir. right, same result. It allows only one instance of the event. I wonder if I did a $(".pubttl").focus(), function ... if it would work.

Comment: Hello Charless, is it possible for you to post the entire code? because i use a similar script which runs perfectly fine for finding out books in an ajax query - http://shabdasnehalibrary.com/ - try the searchbox on the top right.

Comment: apart from the above, it is a simple php function.